# scraping next page using scrapy using css

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am scraping zomato page i need item name and description from next page. I am comfortable with css tags so using those. I have created anaother function parsse_next to do so but not able to find logic what i should write there.I am new to scrapy.I need something like i have written for restaurant name.

```
def parse(self, response):
        rest=response.css(".result-order-flow-title.hover_feedback.zred.bold.fontsize0.ln20::attr(title)").extract() 
        for restaurant  in zip(rest):
            scrapped_info={
            'restaurant':restaurant[0],
            } 

            yield scrapped_info
        nextpage=response.css('.result-order-flow-title.hover_feedback.zred.bold.fontsize0.ln20::attr(href)').extract()
        if nextpage is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(nextpage),callback=self.parsenext)
    def parsenext(self,response):
```

Comment: how can i get similar css code for item name and descriptions?

Comment: why don't you simply use `parse` again as callback?

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(self, response):
    rest=response.css(".result-order-flow-title.hover_feedback.zred.bold.fontsize0.ln20::attr(title)").extract() 
    for restaurant  in zip(rest):
        scrapped_info={
        'restaurant':restaurant[0],
        } 

        yield scrapped_info
    nextpage=response.css('.result-order-flow-title.hover_feedback.zred.bold.fontsize0.ln20::attr(href)').extract()
    if nextpage is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(nextpage),callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: have not tested but from what i see this should be the answer you're looking for. you want to re-use the same method each time.